# How do I read an image using Rawpy image processing library, from a URL?

Tags: python, urllib, libraw, rawpy

How do I read an image using the rawpy library, from a url?

I have tried

```
filepath = www.google.com/image.jpeg

im = rawpy.imread(filepath)
```

but it doesn't work.

I looked deeper into rawpy's code and it says it takes "path or file".

I have also tried other methods like using tempfile, an in memory object, BytesIO, but none of it works.

I would appreciate some help on this please.

Edit One:

In regards to the urllib.request library, these were the errors I got:

i)

```
import rawpy
import io
import urllib

filepath = 'https://filesamples.com/samples/image/jpeg/sample_640%C3%97426.jpeg'

data = urllib.request.urlopen(filepath).read()
stream = io.BytesIO(data)
im = rawpy.imread(stream)
```

with the resultant error

```
LibRawFileUnsupportedError                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-7965dccc6908> in <module>
     35 stream = io.BytesIO(data)
---> 36 im = rawpy.imread(stream)
     37 
     38 """

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rawpy/__init__.py in imread(pathOrFile)
     16     d = RawPy()
     17     if hasattr(pathOrFile, 'read'):
---> 18         d.open_buffer(pathOrFile)
     19     else:
     20         d.open_file(pathOrFile)

rawpy/_rawpy.pyx in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.open_buffer()

rawpy/_rawpy.pyx in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.handle_error()

LibRawFileUnsupportedError: b'Unsupported file format or not RAW file'
```

ii)

```
import rawpy
import io
import urllib
import tempfile
import shutil

filepath = 'https://filesamples.com/samples/image/jpeg/sample_640%C3%97426.jpeg'

with urllib.request.urlopen(filepath) as response:
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete = False) as tmp_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response,tmp_file)
        im = rawpy.imread(tmp_file)
```

with the resultant error

```
LibRawIOError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-ae0405bcc04a> in <module>
     42         shutil.copyfileobj(response,tmp_file)
---> 43         im = rawpy.imread(tmp_file)
     44 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rawpy/__init__.py in imread(pathOrFile)
     16     d = RawPy()
     17     if hasattr(pathOrFile, 'read'):
---> 18         d.open_buffer(pathOrFile)
     19     else:
     20         d.open_file(pathOrFile)

rawpy/_rawpy.pyx in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.open_buffer()

rawpy/_rawpy.pyx in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.handle_error()

LibRawIOError: b'Input/output error'
```

iii)

```
import rawpy
import io
import urllib
import tempfile
import shutil

filepath = 'https://filesamples.com/samples/image/jpeg/sample_640%C3%97426.jpeg'

with urllib.request.urlopen(filepath) as response:
    data = response.read()
    im = rawpy.imread(data)
```

with the resultant error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-f10bfdef4333> in <module>
     55     data = response.read() 
---> 56     im = rawpy.imread(data)
     57 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rawpy/__init__.py in imread(pathOrFile)
     18         d.open_buffer(pathOrFile)
     19     else:
---> 20         d.open_file(pathOrFile)
     21     return d

rawpy/_rawpy.pyx in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.open_file()

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Edit Two:
Other stuff I've tried that didn't use the urllib library were

i) in memory file

```
import io
import rawpy 

filepath = 'https://filesamples.com/samples/image/jpeg/sample_640%C3%97426.jpeg'

response = requests.get(filepath)
in_mem_file = io.BytesIO(response.content)
im = rawpy.imread(in_mem_file)
```

with the resultant error

```
LibRawFileUnsupportedError                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-1ef650bdc042> in <module>
     48 response = requests.get(filepath)
     49 in_mem_file = io.BytesIO(response.content)
---> 50 im = rawpy.imread(in_mem_file)
     51 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rawpy/__init__.py in imread(pathOrFile)
     16     d = RawPy()
     17     if hasattr(pathOrFile, 'read'):
---> 18         d.open_buffer(pathOrFile)
     19     else:
     20         d.open_file(pathOrFile)

rawpy/_rawpy.pyx in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.open_buffer()

rawpy/_rawpy.pyx in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.handle_error()

LibRawFileUnsupportedError: b'Unsupported file format or not RAW file'
```

ii) smart open

```
from smart_open import open
import rawpy 

filepath = 'https://filesamples.com/samples/image/jpeg/sample_640%C3%97426.jpeg'

def get_file(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as s3_source:
        return s3_source
        
s3_source = get_file(filepath)
im = rawpy.imread(s3_source)
```

with the resultant error

```
LibRawIOError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-03b94616ed66> in <module>
     55         return s3_source
     56 s3_source = get_file(filepath)
---> 57 im = rawpy.imread(s3_source)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rawpy/__init__.py in imread(pathOrFile)
     16     d = RawPy()
     17     if hasattr(pathOrFile, 'read'):
---> 18         d.open_buffer(pathOrFile)
     19     else:
     20         d.open_file(pathOrFile)

rawpy/_rawpy.pyx in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.open_buffer()

rawpy/_rawpy.pyx in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.handle_error()

LibRawIOError: b'Input/output error'
```

Edit Three (Solution):

Ok I managed to resolve it by using raw image format data (.dng).

Here is my code

```
import rawpy
import BytesIO
import imageio

filepath = 'www.google.com/sample_file.dng'
response = requests.get(filepath)
raw = rawpy.imread(BytesIO(response.content))
rgb = raw.postprocess()
imageio.imsave('test_rawpy.jpeg', rgb)
```

Comment: You might consider adding the `python` tag. And putting back the `import` statements. And surrounding strings with quotes. And using sensible URLs. And adding error messages...

Comment: *And* researching how to fetch a file from the web server into a `bytes` object... you might have heard of `urllib.request.urlopen`? then you'd have solved your own question. you'll need to dig into that `rawpy` thing and find out how it can decode data from a `bytes` object so you don't have to needlessly store the web server's response to a file, only to load it again in the next line.

Comment: I've tried the urllib.request, and have added the errors I got from it to the question. How do I find how rawpy can decode data from a bytes object? I've searched google and can't find any article/stack overflow article on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPEG is not a [Raw Image Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format).
You need to send some raw data as input.

So,

1. If you just want to process some JPEGs, try [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html).
2. If you want to process raw images, change your input data.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I used a raw image format (.dng) and manage to read and save it. 

I've added the solution to the question.